# tf.function causes out of scope error when inputs passed to add_loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Can loss terms be manually added with add_loss inside a tensorflow graph? The below example for using add_loss is largely copied from

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#the_add_loss_method

but with `@tf.function` added to the layer's call method.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

def main():
    layer = ActivityRegularizationLayer()
    inputs = tf.constant(5.)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y = layer(inputs)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(y)
        loss += sum(layer.losses)
    grad = tape.gradient(loss, layer.trainable_weights)
    print(f"loss={float(loss)}, grad={grad}")

class ActivityRegularizationLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, rate=1e-2):
        super().__init__()
        self.rate = rate

    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs):
        self.add_loss(self.rate * tf.reduce_sum(inputs))
        return inputs
```

Running the above leads to the error

```
The tensor <tf.Tensor 'mul:0' shape=() dtype=float32> cannot be accessed from here, because it was defined in FuncGraph(name=call, id=46917885252656), which is out of scope.
```

Removing the decorator makes things run successfully

```
loss=5.050000190734863, grad=[]
```

as does removing the line adding `sum(layer.losses)` to the total loss

```
loss=5.0, grad=[]
```

Additional details

- `python 3.9.12`
- `tensorflow 2.8.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32058#issuecomment-592664998

In summary, this is a known behavior and the solution is to "wrap your whole training step or training loop in a tf.function"

```
def main():
    model = MyModel()
    inputs = tf.constant(5.)
    loss, grad = model.train_step(inputs)
    print(f"loss={float(loss)}, grad={grad}")

class MyModel(keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.reg = ActivityRegularizationLayer()
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.reg(inputs)
    
    @tf.function
    def train_step(self, data):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y = self(data)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(y)
            loss += sum(self.losses)
        grad = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_weights)
        return loss, grad

class ActivityRegularizationLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, rate=1e-2):
        super().__init__()
        self.rate = rate

    def call(self, inputs):
        self.add_loss(self.rate * tf.reduce_sum(inputs))
        return inputs
```

Comment: Of course I only am able to find something addressing my question after posting about it on SO :/